# why my django rest_framework does not work?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework

im trying to use a SearchFilter in django, but i dont understand why its not work

here are my models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
'''
Modelo de pais
'''
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Nombre de pais', null=False, blank=False)

class Category(models.Model):
    '''
    Modelo de categoria
    '''
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre de ciudad', null=False, blank=False)


class Client(models.Model):
    '''
    Modelo de cliente
    '''
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_client = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Client country', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                null=False, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Ciudad de residencia', null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Client category', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                null=False, blank=False)
    user_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

here is my view:

```
class ClientViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Api view encargada de administrar la
    informacion del modelo cliente
    """
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('city')
```

when i make a request to my api i get all records in database for model client.

Comment: Make sure `search_fields` is  a tuple or list. In your code above `search_fields` is `string`, not tuple or list. If want to tuple with 1 element, need to add comma.  `search_fields = ('city', )`

Comment: When request neet to providing quey params in your url: `http://example.com/api/users?search=rome`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are not providing query parameters to the api endpoint.

Try

```
<api_endpoint>?city=rome
```